# GmailMessage to PDF

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

Google Apps Script - Gmail

Would a `GmailMessage` (`GmailThread`) `.getAsPdf()` method be implemented? The expected output would be the same as print to PDF available in Gmail. This function is available on the website, so why not in Script?

This is necessary to quickly distribute select Gmail conversations to others/externals as PDF.

Also, `GmailMessage.getAttachments()` though in the online documents, does not exist in reality. Will this be implemented?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and worked well (not sure it's the only approach):

```
function getattach(){
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
var attach = message.getAttachments();
Logger.log(attach[0].getDataAsString() )
if(attach.length>0){
var file=DocsList.createFile(attach[0])
var pdf=file.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
// for test purpose I send the pdf as attachment
var attach_to_send = {fileName: 'pdftest.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
   MailApp.sendEmail('emailadress@gmail.com', 'Your test as PDF ', 'see attachment', {attachments:[attach_to_send]});
file.setTrashed(true);// delete after use ;-)
}
}
```

EDIT 1:removed

EDIT 2: here is a new version with the body in pdf attachment, html is supported as well (using DocsList services) , temporary docs are deleted. In one word : quite satisfying ;-)

```
function getAttachAndBody(){
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
  var attach = message.getAttachments();
  var body = message.getBody();//is a string
  var bodydochtml = DocsList.createFile('body.html', body, "text/html")
  var bodyId=bodydochtml.getId()
  var bodydocpdf = bodydochtml.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  if(attach.length>0){
    var file=DocsList.createFile(attach[0])
    var pdf=file.getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
    var attach_to_send = {fileName: 'pdftest.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
    var body_to_send = {fileName: 'body.pdf',content:bodydocpdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
    MailApp.sendEmail('emailadress@gmail.com', 'transfer email as pdf : body & attachment', 'see attachment', {attachments:[attach_to_send,body_to_send]});
    file.setTrashed(true);
    DocsList.getFileById(bodyId).setTrashed(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: var attach = message.getAttachments(); <= this line still works? I get a method not found exception

Comment: you should ensure that the last message in your inbox has an attachment (convertible to pdf), this test function lacks of some check routines ... it's just a test for the getAs pdf feature ;-)

Comment: getAttachments works now. Don't know what ahppened before. How about PDFing a gmail message ?

Comment: just to mention that my answer has been updated with a EDIT2 that works pretty well ;-)

Comment: See https://sites.google.com/site/fileurltodrive/gmail-drive-backup for current version.